# Удаление файла через некоторое время python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня на сервер скачивается определенный файл, который через определенное время нужно удалить, как это можно реализовать? И нужно чтобы он не останавливал работу всего кода

Comment: ваш питон код чтото скачивает ? добавьте thread sleep 99999 os.remove(файл)

Comment: Ну или на кронтаб повесить проверку и чистку старых файлов, если таковых будет много и нет гарантии, что сервер не перегружается иногда